# Testing for a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Lets say you have a set S which is a ring and you are trying to find out if it is a field.
Would it just be enough to test whether it has a multiplicative inverse or not? 
The steps I thought of taking are 
I pick 2 elements from set s for example $$\left [\begin{array}{cc}2 & 0 \\0 & 2\end{array}\right]$$ and $$\left [\begin{array}{cc}3 & 0 \\0 & 3\end{array}\right]$$

I multiply them together to get $0$
I then do $$\left [\begin{array}{cc}2 & 0 \\0 & 2\end{array}\right]^{-1} * \left [\begin{array}{cc}2 & 0 \\0 & 2\end{array}\right] * \left [\begin{array}{cc}3 & 0 \\0 & 3\end{array}\right]$$
and this equals $$\left [\begin{array}{cc}3 & 0 \\0 & 3\end{array}\right]$$ 
Because it does not equal 0, T is not a field. 
Is this proof right?

Comment: Besides the fact it must be commutative? No: existence of inverses of nonzero elements is exactly what you need.

Comment: @nikolajk  I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field must be a **commutative** group under multiplication, so you have to test also commutativity of multiplication.

Added after OP edit.

If you are working with matrix of the form 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
k&0\\
0&k
\end{bmatrix}
$
to show that tey are a field as subring of $M(2,\mathbb{R})$, you have to proof that:

$
I=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$
is the neutral element, i.e.
$
\begin{bmatrix}
k&0\\
0&k
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
k&0\\
0&k
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
k&0\\
0&k
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1/k&0\\
0&1/k
\end{bmatrix}
$

and
$
\begin{bmatrix}
k&0\\
0&k
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
h&0\\
0&h
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
h&0\\
0&h
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
k&0\\
0&k
\end{bmatrix}
$

All is easy.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: I don't undersand your edit. The matrices of the form $kI$, as in your exemple, **are a field**. You have just showed (without proof) that there is a neutral element, but you have to  **find** $A^{-1}$ and prove that $AB=BA$.

Comment: what do you mean by neutral element?

Comment: You can pose another question for this.